# Moving a certain distance at the time using a button in Cocos2d

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I got a method called when my button is pressed, one for the right and one for the left button which can be seen below.

Right now the sprite doesn't move at all as the sprite loads in the centre, but What I want to accomplish is that the sprite moves from the centre and to the left or right of the screen when the appropriate button is pressed, quite easy (I can do this my self).

BUT I want it so that if, "say the right button is pressed and the sprite is all over at the right hand side one can press the left button once to move to the middle of the screen, then if one wants, press it again to move all the way over to the left side and vice versa".

Now how can i make the same button being able to move it to the middle then if pressed again all over to the other side?

My current code only moves it from either side to the middle

```
-(void) btnRightTapped: (id) sender{

CCLOG(@"Left button Tapped");


CGSize viewSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].viewSize;

if (_claw.position.x >= viewSize.width / 2) {

    CCLOG(@"Left button Tapped inside if statement");

    float clawSpeed = - viewSize.width / 400.0;
    float distanceToMoveClaw = clawSpeed;

    float newXClaw = _claw.position.x + distanceToMoveClaw;
    float newYClaw = _claw.position.y;

    _claw.position = ccp(newXClaw, newYClaw);

    [self schedule:@selector(btnRightTapped:) interval:0.02];
    [self unschedule:@selector(btnLeftTapped:)];


}


else [self unschedule:@selector(btnRightTapped:)];

}



 -(void) btnLeftTapped: (id) sender{

CCLOG(@"Right button Tapped");



CGSize viewSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].viewSize;

if (_claw.position.x <= viewSize.width / 2) {


    float clawSpeed = viewSize.width / 400.0;
    float distanceToMoveClaw = clawSpeed;

    float newXClaw = _claw.position.x + distanceToMoveClaw;
    float newYClaw = _claw.position.y;

    _claw.position = ccp(newXClaw, newYClaw);


    [self schedule:@selector(btnLeftTapped:) interval:0.02];
    [self unschedule:@selector(btnRightTapped:)];

}

else [self unschedule:@selector(btnLeftTapped:)];

}
```

Tanks =)

Comment: quite simply you check for the node's x position and if its not near the center you move it to the center first, otherwise you move it to the left/right border

Comment: Could you show how to do this with an example?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out, had to use CCActionMoveTo instead of the schedule methods =)